# How can i extract all values from dictionary with (unique key and max value)

Tags: python, dictionary

How can I extract all values from a dictionary via (unique key and max value)?

Example:

```
{('117', 14): 10, ('113', 11): 5, ('117', 16): 3, ('113', 5): 1}
```

Output will be:

```
{('117', 14): 10, ('113', 11): 5}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `itertools.groupby`:

```
import itertools
d = {('117', 14): 10, ('113', 11): 5, ('117', 16): 3, ('113', 5): 1}
new_d = [list(b) for _, b in itertools.groupby(sorted(d.items(), key=lambda x:x[0][0]), key=lambda x:x[0][0])]
final_result = dict(max(i, key=lambda x:x[-1]) for i in new_d)
```

Output:

```
{('113', 11): 5, ('117', 14): 10}
```